# OpenJDK only: Why does getResourceAsStream() not return MANIFEST.MF in executable JAR

Tags: java

I have a curious situation. My code does not load the `MANIFEST.MF` using `getResourceAsStream()` on OpenJDK 1.6. On Oracle JDK 1.6+ it works well. I came across this when I was accidently running my code on OpenJDK.

**main() method:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    InputStream is = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    char[] c = new char[2048];
    int read;

    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();

    while ((read = isr.read(c)) > 0) {
        b.append(c, 0, read);
    }

    System.out.println(b.toString());
}
```

**Maven JAR plugin definition:**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>net.noorg.test.Main</mainClass>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Using OpenJDK 1.6:**

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_18"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8.7) (6b18-1.8.7-2~squeeze1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode, sharing)
$ java -jar target/test-load-resource-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0_18 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
```

**Using Sun JDK 1.6:**

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
$ java -jar target/test-load-resource-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: ABC
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_07
Main-Class: net.noorg.test.Main
```

- Who's wrong - OpenJDK or I?
- Whats the reason for this?
- Is this only related to the Manifest or would this affect all resources?

---

## Edit 1:

- Both execution use the same .jar
- Maven is running on Oracle JDK 1.7
- I'm running a system with two JDKs installed "defining" them trough `JAvA_HOME` and `PATH`
- I'm running the .jar on one machine using different `JAVA_HOME`'s set and `PATH`s set to `java` in two different consoles.

### In addition to the above outputs

**Open JDK (alternative JAVA_HOME/PATH not set):**

```
$ echo "$JAVA_HOME" ; which java

/usr/bin/java
```

**Sun JDK set:**

```
$ echo "$JAVA_HOME" ; which java
/usr/local/jdk
/usr/local/jdk/bin/java
```

---

## Edit 2:

If the `JAVA_HOME` is properly defined for the OpenJDK (by default) it's the same.

```
$ echo "$JAVA_HOME" ; which java
/usr/java
/usr/bin/java
```

So it's not related to the empty `JAVA_HOME` on my account.

Comment: Do you use the same jars?

Comment: The output shows different values for `Created-By`, that's why I'm asking about jars. Can you show the content of MANIFEST.MF?

Comment: That why I became aware of this. I actually was reading the manifest through the `java.util.jar.Manifest` class and it didn't returned my manifest entry. I thought I have used `Manifest` the wrong way. To falsify this I printed the loaded resource as string and there it is. Finally I've created a small example reduced to Maven + jar-plugin + Main class with that code.

Comment: I would also ask to verify that it is the same jar with the same MANIFEST.MF. Easily a build can go wrong. The other issue is with class loaders, in IDEs for instance. You might try `InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");`.

Comment: Added further explanaition to the question. -- I've `cd`ed into the same directory within two different consoles (at almost the same time). Build in console 1, run in console 2 and 3.

Comment: I have seen issues because of [this bug](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4639129). Does a **jar -xvf** on both platforms produce the same MANIFEST.MF? Also you can try modifying the MF size which I have seen make a difference (believe it or not). But in your case it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with openJDK 6, and maybe it is too late for the answer but, I had the same problem but using JDK 1.7.0.2. I see you are using maven

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>        
                <configuration>
                  <archive>
                    <manifest>
                       <mainClass>net.noorg.test.Main</mainClass>
                       <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                      <classpathPrefix>classes/META-INF/lib</classpathPrefix>              
                    </manifest>
                  </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

That's the way I could made it run, I strongly recommend you to not use openJDK6, I think with the arrival of JDK 7 there are many things you can do and without risk of errors and a better performance for security.